# EF Lambda Linq Query With Navigation Lists

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I cant seem to finish my linq statement with the correct select.
So far I have the following, but the problem is it results in a 'Select' of only the CategoryTypes's, when I want a select on everything:

```
var qwe = dc.LeadTypes
            .Include("DataTypes")
            .Include("DataTypes.CategoryTypes")
            .Where<LeadType>(x => x.Disabled == false)
            .SelectMany(x => x.DataTypes)
            .Where(x => x.Disabled == false)
            .SelectMany(x => x.CategoryTypes)
            .Where(x => x.Disabled == false)
            .ToList();
```

Resulting SQL

```
SELECT 
[Extent3].[CategoryTypeID] AS [CategoryTypeID], 
[Extent3].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent3].[DataTypeID] AS [DataTypeID], 
[Extent3].[Disabled] AS [Disabled]
FROM   [LeadLookup].[LeadType] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [LeadLookup].[DataType] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[LeadTypeID] = [Extent2].    [LeadTypeID]
INNER JOIN [LeadLookup].[CategoryType] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[DataTypeID] =      [Extent3].[DataTypeID]
WHERE (0 = [Extent1].[Disabled]) AND (0 = [Extent2].[Disabled]) AND (0 = [Extent3].  [Disabled])
```

The reason I am doing this is because I have a disabled column on each of the three tables and I do not want to return those rows.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what result you want - which `LeadType` entities would you exclude based on their `CategoryTypes`?

Comment: I think .Include is not that easy, there are certain rules when it will work and when not (sorry, cant find the reference for that...):, If your problem is that the include "seems" not to work, you could try (include on the result):
var result = (dc.LeadTypes.Where<LeadType>(x => x.Disabled == false)
.SelectMany(x => x.DataTypes).Where(x => x.Disabled == false).SelectMany(x => x.CategoryTypes).Where(x => x.Disabled == false)).Include("DataTypes")
     .Include("DataTypes.CategoryTypes")  .ToList();

Comment: Thanks, I tied that, but its the SelectMany that is causing the problem since it returns an enumerable of the navigation type.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i understood your requirements, but try this to return LeadTypes with all it entities enabled

```
var qwe = (from lt in dc.LeadTypes
           where !lt.Disabled
           select new LeadType
           {
               DataTypes = from dt in lt.DataTypes
                           where !dt.Disabled
                           select new DataType
                           {
                               CategoryTypes = dt.CategoryTypes.Where(ct => !ct.Disabled),
                               // rest of dt values
                           }
               // rest of lt values
           }).ToList();
```

Comment: Didn't quite work, that limited all the way to the parent list LeadTypes! Only returned LeadTypes where Diabled columns for the DataTypes table and Categories table not set.

Comment: what are you expecting from query?

Comment: To select LeadTypes,DataTypes & CategoryTypes. At the moment it is just returning CategoryTypes.

Comment: ok, let me check:

return enabled LeadTypes, with enabled DataTypes and enabled CategoryTypes?

Answer (score 0):

If you use include() you can't project columns into a different shape.
With projection columns can't have the same name.

[image: result]

```
var qwe = dc.LeadTypes.Where(x => x.Disabled == false)
        .SelectMany(x => x.DataTypes.Where(y => y.Disabled == false), (lead, data) => new
        {
            disabledLeadType = lead.Disabled,
            disabledDataType = data.Disabled,
            idDataType = data.Id,
            categoryType = data.CategoryTypes
        }
        )
        .SelectMany(x => x.categoryType.Where(y => y.Disabled == false), (lead_data, category) => new
        {
        lead_data.disabledLeadType, lead_data.disabledDataType, lead_data.idDataType,
        disabledCategoryType = category.Disabled,
        idCatergoryType = category.Id
        }
        )
        .ToList();
```